# Flask - got multiple values for keyword argument 'eventid' - Decorators

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently running a Python Flask application that makes use of the following decorator:

```
def login_required(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'phone' in session:
            user = User.query.filter_by(phone = session['phone']).first()
            if user:
                return fn(user, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrapper
```

I have the following view:

```
@app.route('/delete/<eventid>')
@login_required
def delete(eventid):
```

That is being called by the following line:

```
url_for('delete', eventid=event.uid)
```

This produces the following error:

```
delete() got multiple values for keyword argument 'eventid'
```

The delete() function works when the decorator is NOT used.
The decorator works when it is NOT used with the delete() function.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your wrapper function passes an additional argument `user` to the decorated function (in this case `delete`)

```
return fn(user, *args, **kwargs)
```

But your `delete` function only takes a single arg called `eventid`. Python interprets the first arg (user) as the eventid arg, but then gets another keyword argument for the same name, hence the odd error message.

It's essentially like this:

```
>>> def delete(eventid):
    print eventid

>>> delete('user', eventid='test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    delete('user', eventid='test')
TypeError: delete() got multiple values for keyword argument 'eventid'
```

So it works without the decorator because no user arg is passed in. Just add the user as the first arg to the delete function.